# Updating Core Data from custom NSCell

Tags: macos, core-data, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller, nscell

I have a custom `NSCell` (actually subclassing `NSTextFieldCell`), which is used both in a standalone editor, and in an `NSTableColumn` (bound to Core Data through `NSArrayController`). When the user changes the value, I call `-[NSCell setObjectValue:]` to update the value (it's an `NSNumber`). This works in the standalone editor, since when it's done I manually update the binding on it.

```
[self setObjectValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:newValue]];
```

That step (updating the bound field) is missing when the cell is in an `NSTableView` - the updated value shows up while the user's editing (with mouse tracking), but as soon as that's over, the value snaps back to the persisted value.

The `NSTableColumn` is bound to a key of `-[NSArrayController arrangedObjects]`. Is there some sort of call to "commitEditing" or "updateBinding" that I'm missing? I couldn't find any useful functions in the docs for `NSCell` or `NSTableView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, I implemented `-tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:` in my `NSArrayController` subclass. I get the instance of my `NSManagedObject` subclass from the Row argument, and then manually assign the new model from the ObjectValue argument. I still don't know why this is necessary, when the text cells do this automatically, but it works.